# Activar - desactivar class active de un nav-item con bootstrap 4

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Saludos quisiera saber si es posible activar la class active segun a donde se haga click, he intentado con unos script que encontre en la web pero no me han funcionado.

La forma en la que yo lo estoy haciendo es:
Tengo un archivo php de donde hago el llamado de otro archivo php que es donde tengo el nav-bar.

Archivo al que se le hace llamado en este caso este archivo se llama **generarpedido.php**

```
<?php
    include('../funciones/functions.php');

    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Debes iniciar sesión primero";
        header('location: ../login.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Generador de Pedido</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <!--link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/logo-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<?php include("includes/head.php"); ?>
<?php echo 'Bienvenido ' .$_SESSION['user']['nombre']; ?>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>   

</body>
</html>>
```

Y esto otro es el archivo **head.php** como pueden ver al final he incluido uno de los tantos script on los que he probado para que desactive la class active a donde estaba originalmente y la active en donde se hace clic.

```
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" style="background-color:  #cca700;">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
          <img src="https://local.jesuministrosymas.com.ve/image/LOGO.png" width="180" height="30" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.php"><i class="fas fa-home fa-fw"></i> Inicio
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a  class="nav-link" href="generarpedido.php"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down fa-fw"></i> Generar Pedido</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-money-bill-alt fa-fw"></i> Pagos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Contactenos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-fw"></i>  Ajustes
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-address-card fa-fw"></i> Perfil</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-history fa-fw"></i> Historial</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="nav-link" href="../index.php?logout='1'"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>

 Salir</a>
        </div>
      </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

<script>
$('li.nav-item').click(function(){
    $('li.nav-item').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Debería servirte algo como esto

```js
$('li a').click(function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('ul').find('li.active,a.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
        $this.parent().addClass('active');

    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" style="background-color:#cca700;">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="https://local.jesuministrosymas.com.ve/image/LOGO.png" width="180" height="30" alt="">
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home fa-fw"></i> Inicio
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a  class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down fa-fw"></i> Generar Pedido</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-money-bill-alt fa-fw"></i> Pagos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Contactenos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-fw"></i>  Ajustes
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-address-card fa-fw"></i> Perfil</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-history fa-fw"></i> Historial</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="nav-link" href="../index.php?logout='1'"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>

 Salir</a>
        </div>
      </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Como buenas prácticas de programación es recomendable insertar los estilos `css` en el `head` de tu página y los `script` al final (antes del `</body>`) para una mejor optimización de nuestra página y/o sistema web; ahora bien, existen distintos puntos de vista de acuerdo a lo mencionado pero es harina de otro costal.

En cuanto a lo que mencionas sobre los links, sólo debes comentar la línea que dice `e.preventDefault()`, *la cual es una forma de prevenir el comportamiento al realizar una acción, que este caso es un click sobre el link*

**Ahora bien, si no es un requisito para ti que algún link este activo por defecto, también podrías utilizar esto:**

```
$('li a').click(function(e) {
   //e.preventDefault();
   $('a').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Nos comentas =)

Comment: `closest()` está Deprecated

Comment: Eso es? Un error? No entendí el comentario

Comment: Saludos @PauloUrbanoRivera creo que mi error es que no se exactamente donde debo incluir el codigo que me estas sugiriendo, lo estoy colocando entre etiquetas `<script></script>` pero no se si se debe hacer de esa manera, o debo crear un archivo js y cargarlo en el head de mi html, o lo coloco al final del footer despues de cargar la serie de script (jquery, bootstrap) antes de cerrar la etiqueta </body> yo estoy tratando de efectuar todas las combinaciones que te he mencionado sin exito..!! a pesar de que en el ejemplo que me dejastes funciona de manera perfecta..!

Comment: Ya logre ubicar el script al final de la etiqueta html y funciona activar y desactivar la clase active pero no funciona los link. creo que debe ser por lo que comenta @TatoOC que ' closest()' esta descontinuado, pero ahora como podria colocar la funcion intente con `$('li').click(function(){
    $('li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});` sin exito..!

Comment: @JoseMHerreraV Abajo te dejé un ejemplo que funciona perfectamente. Revísalo.

Comment: @JoseMHerreraV Edite la respuesta con una explicación a tus inquietudes; `closest()` no tiene ninguna relación con que los links no "funcionen". Revisalo y nos comentas colega

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera he seguido tus orientaciones pero creo que en la versión de jquery que estoy utilizando con Bootstrap 4 es  la versión /3.3.1/jquery.min.js he revisado la documentación de jquery y alli indican que en efecto `closest()` esta descontinuado y en efecto en el ejemplo que muy gentilmente me haz sugerido ahora si efectua los link pero no desactiva la `class "active"` siempre queda activada en el `<li class="nav-item active">` del index.php de mi ejemplo.

Comment: @JoseMHerreraV en el ejemplo estoy utilizando la misma versión de jQuery que me indicas =/... Ahora bien, te deje otra solución la cual debería funcionarte sin problema aunque _sacrificas una característica para la experiencia de usuario_. Me comentas que tal te va

Comment: Estoy que me doy por vencido y creo que terminare haciendo de manera manual la activacion y desactivacion de la clase active dejare la url de donde esta en tiempo real mi desarrollo (https://virtual.jesuministrosymas.com.ve/u/) el usuario es prueba y la clave 12345 no se si desde algun navegador orientado en developer me puedan ayudar a ver donde esta el error de mi desarrollo, porque yo no logro identificarlo..!

Comment: He implementado el codigo `$(document).ready(function () {
    var links = $('.navbar ul li a');
    $.each(links, function (key, va) {
        if (va.href == document.URL) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});` y funciona perfecto, lo unico es que no le quita el active que esta por defecto en el index.php

Answer (score 0):

De forma sencilla sería:

```js
//  JAVASCRIPT

$('li').on('click',function(e){ 
  $(this).parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active'); 
  $(this).addClass('active');  
});
```

```css
/* CSS */

.active{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p>De click en cualquier Item</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#"></a>Item 1</li>
      <li class=""><a href="#"></a>Item 2</li>
      <li class=""><a href="#"></a>Item 3</li>
      <li class=""><a href="#"></a>Item 4</li>
    </ul>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Saludos @TatoOC en efecto tambien he tratado de implementar tu sugerencia pero sin exito, en el caso del script que sugieres en mi caso queda exactamente igual, los link funcionan pero no desactiva y activa la clase `active` como se espera.